# File Watcher windows service just raising the Onstart event once is this correct?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services

This is my First time writing a Windows Service with a File watcher.This is what I'm trying to accomplish.:

1. Have a Windows Service which checks for text file to change(test.txt).
2. If text file changes. it calls a second program and passes the actual time for now eventually want to pass other parameters.
3. This second program just writes the argument receive to a .txt file(values.txt)

Problem:

1. Start win service.
2. Then change the file and the second program writes the current time to .txt file
3. If I change the file being watched nothing happens.

Question:
Is this how it suppose to work. Just raise the even once after the Service Starts? If yes what do I need to do for the service to keep watching for the file?

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance !

My code is below

MyNewService.vb

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class MyNewService
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    If Not System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource") Then
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource",
        "MyNewLog")
    End If
    EventLog1.Source = "MySource"
    EventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog"

End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
    ' in motion so your service can do its work.
    EventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart")

    Dim watcher As New FileSystemWatcher

    With watcher
        .Filter = "test.txt*"                             'To chatch only txt files
        .IncludeSubdirectories = True
        .NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
        .Path = "C:\Users\uname\Desktop\FSW Test\"            
    End With

    'Add event handlers
    AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler watcher.Created, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler watcher.Deleted, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler watcher.Renamed, AddressOf OnRenamed ' not implemented. Leaving them for future use

    'Begin watching
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
    EventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStop.")
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnContinue()
    EventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnContinue.")
End Sub

Dim lastRead As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
Private Sub OnChanged(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)

    Dim lastWriteTime As DateTime = File.GetLastAccessTime("C:\Users\uname\Desktop\FSW Test\test.txt")

    If lastWriteTime <> lastRead Then  ' Use to skype one of the times this event is raised
        'Opens pogram 'WindowsApplication2.exe' and passes parameters
        RunApp()
        lastRead = lastWriteTime
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub OnRenamed(sender As Object, e As RenamedEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath)
End Sub

Public Sub RunApp()
    Dim test As String = TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss")
    Dim pHelp As New ProcessStartInfo
    With pHelp
        .FileName = "C:\Users\uname\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Substation\TriggerMF\WindowsApplication2\bin\Debug\WindowsApplication2.exe"
        .Arguments = test
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        '.UseShellExecute = True
        .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    End With
    Process.Start(pHelp)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Your `lastWriteTime` logic looks pretty broken.  Very little reason to assume it ever changes again after OnChanged() runs once.

Comment: @HansPassant I saw that on an asnwer to avoid it to raise the event on change twice when the file changes. It works. Do you have any idea about the windows service ? Am I missing something ? Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

Comment: Well, then at least use the LastWriteTime of the file that changed, not some arbitrary .txt file that has nothing to do with the directory you are monitoring.

Comment: @HansPassant Thats my mistake I meant to change my computer name so i dont publish it here but i missed that one. My bad.